# Can't get SFINAE to work in function detector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I've been working on some solutions for some questions that have been recently posted where the original questioners have been trying to query if a method exists in a given class.  I've been trying to develop a solution using a SFINAE approach, but unfortunately I keep coming up empty.

Here was my attempt at a solution that isn't working for a class that allows us to detect if another class has a method called `function()`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct sample_class
{
    void function() {}
};


template<typename T>
class test_size_call
{
    private:
        typedef char yes;
        typedef char (&no)[2];
        int tester[1];

        template <unsigned int>
        struct helper { static const unsigned int value = 1; };

        template<typename R>
        static yes test(int (&a)[helper<sizeof(std::declval<R>().function(), 0)>::value]);

        /* template<typename R>
        static no test(...); */

    public:
        static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(tester)) == sizeof(yes));
};


int main()
{
    cout << "Has function() method: " << test_size_call<sample_class>::value << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The results, if you uncomment the catch-all `test` function, keep coming up as `false`.  With the function commented out, I get a compiler error that there is not version of `test` that will take a `int (&)[1]` argument.  I'm curious why the `declval<R>().function()` doesn't seem to be instantiating properly.  For instance, if I changed it to something very explicit, like `declval<T>().function()` then it works.  Unfortunately that's not SFINAE, because if the class doesn't have a `function()` method, rather than failing silently, I get a compiler error.

I'm sure there is something really simple I'm missing here.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must be a problem with your compiler, Clang correctly prints `1` and `0` for the following code:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class test_size_call
{
    private:
        typedef char yes;
        typedef char (&no)[2];
        int tester[1];

        template <unsigned int>
        struct helper { static const unsigned int value = 1; };

        template<typename R>
        static yes test(int (&a)[helper<sizeof(std::declval<R>().function(), 0)>::value]);

        template<typename R>
        static no test(...);

    public:
        static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(tester)) == sizeof(yes));
};

#include <iostream>

struct sample_class
{
    void function() {}
};

struct sample_class2{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Has function() method: " << test_size_call<sample_class>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "Has function() method 2: " << test_size_call<sample_class2>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

While GCC 4.5.1 [does not](http://ideone.com/BrFyY). Note that it's fixed in GCC 4.7, as pointed out [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2398750#2398750).

Comment: Okay, cool ... this was driving me a bit crazy as I could have swore it should have worked, but as you've pointed out, ideone with `gcc` 4.5.1 isn't giving the expected results.  Since when was `clang` ahead of `gcc` in C++11 compliance?

Comment: @Jason: Since they started working on C++11 support? :P I seriously don't know, but Clang is the most conforming compiler right now IIRC. Except the missing features of course, like lambdas, `constexpr` and initializer lists..

Comment: @Jason: it's not that Clang is ahead as much as it is that Clang aims at being right rather than "complete".

Comment: @Xeo: Regarding `constexpr` and initializer lists, does this still apply ? There's been a lot of worked poured into those two of late so I would expect them to be close to completion but has not been testing.

Comment: @Matthieu: Atleast my snapshot from ~2 weeks ago doesn't support them in any semantic way, only syntactically. For example `for(auto e : {1, 2, 3})` reports "cannot use type 'void' as a range".

Comment: @Xeo: is this supposed to work ? this does not seem to have anything to do with `constexpr` or initializer lists by the way.

Comment: @Matthieu: `{1, 2, 3}` should create an initializer list that is iterated over.

Comment: @Xeo: I just discovered this feature in another thread. There is talk that `#include <initializer_list>` might be required to enable this. Thanks for showing me something new (and shiny !).

Comment: @Matthieu: I included `<initializer_list>` (libc++). :) Maybe I should update my snapshot and recompile.. if it wasn't such a hassle on a VirtualBox thanks to the gigantic amount of RAM needed to link Clang. :(

Comment: @Xeo: I use it directly with mingw... and it is just damn slow :x Oh well, once compiled it works pretty well at least.

Comment: @Xeo: finally found a reference, a commit from Sebastian Redl today: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?rev=148349&view=rev (TL;DR you are right, no CodeGen yet).

Answer (score 2):

Jason, if you are using Visual C++ then SFINAE does not work very well there (in particular it does not seem to work for data members of user-defined types, but it might still work for functions though).

For other compilers you can use something along these lines:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_function
{
  template <typename U, void (U::*f) ()> struct match_;
  template<typename > static char (&select_(...))[2];
  template<typename U> static char (&select_(match_<U, &U::function>* ))[1];

  enum { value = sizeof(select_<T>(0)) == 1 };
};

struct get
{
  void function();
};

int main()
{
  int t[(int)has_function<get>::value];
  (void)t;
}
```

There is a workaround for Visual C++ bug, check Workarounds tab here:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718729/c-type-equality-not-recognized-under-sfinae-context